# Vue CLI 3 Nightwatch page object configuration

Tags: vue.js, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing, pageobjects, vue-cli-3

I'm using Vue CLI 3 version 3.0.5.
In project configuration, I use Nightwatch as e2e test tool.

I try to use page objects, so I had `nightwatch.config.js` file in project root, and add page_objects_path inside like below:

```
{
  page_objects_path : "/tests/e2e/page-objects"
}
```

Then I create `page-objects` folder as this path: `/tests/e2e/page-objects`.

Then I setup a page object `Entry.js` under that folder and try to use it in test:
`/tests/e2e/page-objects/Entry.js`

```
vmodule.exports = {
  'Test Page Object': browser => {
    browser
      .url(process.env.VUE_DEV_SERVER_URL)
      .waitForElementVisible('#app', 5000)
    browser.page.Entry().sayHello()
    browser.end()
  }
}
```

And the error message shows:
`Cannot read property 'Entry' of undefined` .

It looks like my page object setup is not correct...
Could anyone help providing a correct implementation of NightWatch page object in Vue CLI v3.0.5 ? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I know why it won't work.

Because `nightwatch.config.js` is a javascript file, I should export it first, then the plugin can read it.

```
module.export = {
  page_objects_path : "/tests/e2e/page-objects" 
}
```

Sorry for the dumb question.